# How to use image as button in customtkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

at this code im trying to use image as button but its being created next to button

```
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"


img = customtkinter.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open(r"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Customtkinter\images\img.png"))



class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)          # creating grid
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        self.title("Main Screen")                       # creating main screen
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")

        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, image=img)     #button (problem with img)
        self.button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

i were trying to import button from figma using tk designer, but buttons had another colours, and text was moved.
Also if it possible how to create gradient buttons using customtkinter?

Answer (score 0):

Add text = "" at the line you set the image for the button.

```
self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, image=img, text="")
```